# Test inserting values into mongodb (pyspark, pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, mocking

I would like to (locally) test inserting some values into a mongo database. If I run this:

```
import pymongo
import mongomock

@mongomock.patch(
    servers=(("mongodb://null:null@localhost/test", 27017),), on_new="pymongo"
)
def get_mongodb_table():
    return pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://null:null@localhost/test')['test']['table']

table = get_mongodb_table()
table.insert_one({'a': 'b'})  # This works!
table.find_one({})
```

> {'a': 'b', '_id': ObjectId('5d5be9e853f24bf46d268d78')}

However, the following fails:

```
import pyspark
import pymongo
import mongomock

SC = pyspark.SparkContext()

@mongomock.patch(
    servers=(("mongodb://null:null@localhost/test", 27017),), on_new="pymongo"
)
def get_mongodb_table():
    return pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://null:null@localhost/test')['test']['table']

table = get_mongodb_table()

rdd = SC.parallelize([{'a': 0, 'b': 1}])
rdd.foreach(table.insert_one)  # This doesn't work!
```

> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable

How can I fix the test so the error isn't raised? How can I test insert a dict from an rdd into a mongo database?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reference your Mongo connection **within your RDD** that you'd previously established **outside your RDD**. Spark is trying to serialize this connection in order to process it inside each RDD, but it is unable to because of the properties of a Database object.

How to resolve: You will need to create your connection within your RDD processing.

```py
import pyspark
import pymongo
import mongomock

SC = pyspark.SparkContext()

@mongomock.patch(
    servers=(("mongodb://null:null@localhost/test", 27017),), on_new="pymongo"
)
def get_mongodb_table():
    return pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://null:null@localhost/test')['test']['table']

def create_and_insert(x):
    table = get_mongodb_table()
    table.insert_one(x)

rdd = SC.parallelize([{'a': 0, 'b': 1}])
rdd.foreach(create_and_insert)
```

However, **I highly recommend** using foreachPartition instead of foreach when uploading to a database. foreach creates a separate connection for every element. foreachPartition creates a separate connection for each partition of elements, which will be a significantly smaller number when the number of elements is larger than what you have here.

Comment: Thanks! But then, how can I check that the values were actually inserted successfully into the table? If I run `get_mongodb_table().find_one({})` after the code you wrote, it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with using libraries, you could use the following solution:

```py
import pymongo_spark
pymongo_spark.activate()

# save rdd to the empty mongodb collection
rdd.saveToMongoDB('mongodb://host_ip:port/db.collection')
```

You can also use this to read the MongoDB collection into an RDD:

```py
# create rdd for the mongodb collection
rdd = sc.mongoRDD('mongodb://host_ip:port/db.collection')
print(rdd.first())
print(rdd.count())
```